# css positioning i am having a problem with positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am new to web development, I have a small problem with positioning i placed a

element with content in it all of the word are grumble up instead of be in one line . can anyone help me with a solution. positioning has been a big problem for me so far so if you guys know any sources where i can learn more about css positioning

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yantramanav:100');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One');

html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.intro {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 display: table;
 top: 0;
 background-size: cover;
 background:url(https://picstatio.com/download/1600x900/864423/food-dishes-beer-bottle.jpg)no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
.intro .inner{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: none;
}
.content {
 max-width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
.content h1 {
 font-family: "Yantramana";
 font-size: 600%;
 font-weight: 100;
 color: #E1EFE9;
 line-height: 70%;
}
.btn{
 font-family: "montserrat";
 font-size: 135%;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: orange;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: solid #ffffff;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border-radius: 9px;
 transition: all 0.7s;
}
.btn:hover {
 color: #CBDFD6;
 border: solid #CBDFD6;

}
.about-us{
 height:100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 display: table;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
}
.ab-content {
 font-family: "Poiret One";
 font-weight: lighter;
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 150%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.ab-p{
 position: absolute;
 top: 10%;
 left: 50%;
 font-weight: lighter;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 font-family: "montserrat";
}

.color {
 color:orange;
}
/*--- Media Queries --*/
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {

}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
 <title>Full Screen Landing Page</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="css/waypoints.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/waypoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <section class="intro">
  <div class="inner">
   <div class="content">
    <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="bounceInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".3s">
     <h1>Find <span class="color">Your</span> Taste!</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="slideInLeft" data-os-animation-delay="0s">
     <a class="btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section class="about-us">
  <div class="ab-inner">
   <div class="ab-content">
    <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="slideInLeft" data-os-animation-delay="0s">
     <h2 class="center">Our Mission</h2>
     <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="slideInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".5s">
      <p class="ab-p">Our mission is to provide the best food ingedients.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your content class is 600px in width and the text and font size of your text is big therefore it will break into a new line if the content is bigger than the width. Increase the width or reduce the font size and the text will be in a single line

Comment: You should read about `position: absolute` and what it actually does. It is almost certainly the wrong thing to be using here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you would like the "Our Mission" section to be centered and readable.

```
.ab-p {
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: "montserrat";
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Recommendation: don't use `position:absolute` unless you absolutely needed it, because this rule removes the element from the automatic positioning of the browser - meaning you are in complete control of where to position it.

Answer (score 1):

"Relative" "position" relates positions, so this can avoid mess.

```css
.ab-content {
    font-family: "Poiret One";
    font-weight: lighter;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 150%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
   }
```

Comment: w3school position property